# Is it greedy of me to desire heaven?

Tags: halal-haram, jannah

1.) Lately, I have been having a psychological crisis. Does Allah want me to go to Jannah? I go to the masjid for young adults and these sexist boys whom I grown up with. (Their parents are close friends with my parents.) They bully me and they are discouraging me. I overheard them saying they are praying to Allah so I will not go to Jannah because I do not deserve to go because I am selfish? I once said I want to go to the highest Jannah. They heard and said it was selfish of me. They said I do not deserve to go. You know the hadith "none of you is a believer till you love your brother what you love for yourself." I told them that hadith and their response was was that the hadith applies for muslim men to help each other and not muslim men to want the muslim women as they want for themselves-whether mahram or not- i got discouraged and been feeling guilty. I earlier said that I do not want to Jannah because I felt unworthy. I still do. But I feel I am too selfish and greedy to want the best for myself. I want good people to go to Jannah but not myself anymore. I do not want to go to hell either because of the pain. But not heaven because I do not deserve it because I am greedy to want not only Jannah but Jannah furdouse.

2.) Is it sinful for me to not want Jannah? Is it sinful for me to give up on myself? I know Allah will forgive me but I feel that I do not deserve it and If I want Jannah then I am greedy. Rigbt now, I want to go to Jannah again but I feel unworthy and guilty.

Comment: My sincere advice to you, please go and ask your local Imam those types of questions.

Comment: I cannot go to the masjid. It is small. The scholar is busy for me to ask

Comment: what is your opinion, brother?

Comment: This is the human. We are what we are. We want the paradise, nobody can change that. You may call it greed if you wish, but this is our natural inclination. We want what is good. 

See this hadith: http://sunnah.com/muslim/1/370

Comment: See also: [Qur'an 42:20](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=42&verse=20). Also, try to stay away from people who bully, why do you want to get bullied? Because you enjoy it?

Answer (score 4):

> Am I greedy to desire heaven?

***Absolutely not. If it were the case we would have been warned against it by the Prophet  ﷺ.***

On the contrary, he encouraged us to ask Allah for the *highest* station in Paradise.

On the authority of Abu Huraira, the Messenger of Allah :

> ‏"‏ مَنْ آمَنَ بِاللَّهِ وَرَسُولِهِ، وَأَقَامَ الصَّلاَةَ، وَصَامَ رَمَضَانَ، كَانَ حَقًّا عَلَى اللَّهِ أَنْ يُدْخِلَهُ الْجَنَّةَ هَاجَرَ، فِي سَبِيلِ اللَّهِ، أَوْ جَلَسَ فِي أَرْضِهِ الَّتِي وُلِدَ فِيهَا ‏"‏‏.‏ قَالُوا يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ أَفَلاَ نُنَبِّئُ النَّاسَ بِذَلِكَ‏.‏ قَالَ ‏"‏ إِنَّ فِي الْجَنَّةِ مِائَةَ دَرَجَةٍ أَعَدَّهَا اللَّهُ لِلْمُجَاهِدِينَ فِي سَبِيلِهِ، كُلُّ دَرَجَتَيْنِ مَا بَيْنَهُمَا كَمَا بَيْنَ السَّمَاءِ وَالأَرْضِ، فَإِذَا سَأَلْتُمُ اللَّهَ فَسَلُوهُ الْفِرْدَوْسَ، فَإِنَّهُ أَوْسَطُ الْجَنَّةِ وَأَعْلَى الْجَنَّةِ، وَفَوْقَهُ عَرْشُ الرَّحْمَنِ، وَمِنْهُ تَفَجَّرُ أَنْهَارُ الْجَنَّةِ ‏"‏‏
>
> "Whoever believes in Allah and His Apostle offers prayers perfectly and fasts (the month of) Ramadan then it is incumbent upon Allah to admit him into Paradise, whether he emigrates for Allah's cause or stays in the land where he was born." They (the companions of the Prophet) said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! Should we not inform the people of that?" He said, "There are one-hundred degrees in Paradise which Allah has prepared for those who carry on Jihad in His Cause. The distance between every two degrees is like the distance between the sky and the Earth, ***so if you ask Allah for anything, ask Him for the *Firdaus*, for it is the middle part of Paradise and its highest part***, and at its top there is the Throne of Beneficent, and from it gush forth the rivers of Paradise."
>
> [Saheeh Bukhari, Book 97, Hadeeth 51](https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/97/51)

And there is no contradiction between the *Hadeeth* above and the Hadeeth of loving for others what one loves for their own self, since *Al-Firdaus* it is not necessary that it will be granted to only one individual.

---

> Is it sinful for me to not want *Jannah*?

This question is no longer relevant if it is clear to the OP that there should be no guilt for desiring the best in the Hereafter.

Answer (score 1):

```
السلام عليكم و رحمة الله و بركاته
```

Dearest sis., Subhan Allah

Rasulullaah (PBUH) told his companions in an authentic Hadith that we should ask for Jannah all the time AND to ask for the highest Jannah t'al Firdaus.

There is also a Hadith that if we seek refuge from the hellfire and ask for Jannah we will receive that and that we should ask in salaah. I'm not a scholar at all, have been Muslim 19 years and am senior to you by many many years. My love. These young brothers are a test for you so remain patient and steadfast and just ignore them.

May Allah (SWT) ease all your difficulties in this life and the next and grant you Jannah t'al Firdaus 'ala. Ameeen!

Answer (score -1):

Many men don't think women have right on  anything but jannah is our final destination. Pray to Allah and he will surely help you. As woman there will be many problem faced in our lives especially sexist. One day or another you meet someone sexist. And Allah is the only one to decide whether we belong to jannan or hell. Whether each of them we would have earned it with our own deeds and surely He will be just with everyone. So don't worry about not being able to think this nonsense. See the beauty of jannah and do some research and then pray to Allah that in sha allah tht we all go to Jannah and He protect us from the hell fire. And people like those arent someone to decide whether u deserve jannah or not. Just ignore them and talk to your parents in sha allah they will surely help you. May Allan protect from the hell and evil 
W/salam

Comment: please consider: http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -2):

Do not give up on yourself, ignore if people saying you that you r being selfish
and just Cary on, Allah doesn't forgive people just like that until you don't ask for forgiveness and until u don't promise to do good things

Comment: and ask Allah for highes jannah and protect from helfire